# Parenting issue, how can I keep objects connected without changing origin?

Tags: parent, origin

So I parented a smaller plant to my main one. My issue is that since the origin point of my biggest plant is at the bottom, my smaller plant doesn't stay attached to my main one. It follows the path but isn't staying attached to my plant. Is there a way that I can fix this without changing my origin points? Here's a video of the issue ;
https://vimeo.com/761921403

Comment: You can use specific verts as parent of an object, so the child will follow those verts location, not the origin. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html#vertex-parent

Comment: @FFeller thank you so much! I'll look into it